# Get groups with regex and OR

Tags: regex, groovy

I have something like this

> AD ABCDEFG HIJKLMN
>   AB HIJKLMN
>   AC DJKEJKW SJKLAJL JSHELSJ

Rule: **Always 2 Chars Code (AB|AC|AD) at line beginning then any number of 7 Chars codes following.**

With this regex:

> ^(AB|AC|AD)|((\S{7})?

in this groovy code sample:

> def m= Pattern.compile(/^(AB|AC|AD)|((\S{7})?)/).matcher("AC DJKEJKW SJKLAJL JSHELSJ")
>   println m.getCount()

I always get 8 as count, means it counts the spaces.
How do I get 4 groups (as expected) without spaces ?

Thanks from a not-yet-regex-expert
Sven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this code:

```
def input = [ 'AD ABCDEFG HIJKLMN', 'AB HIJKLMN', 'AC DJKEJKW SJKLAJL JSHELSJ' ]

def regexp = /^(AB|AC|AD)|((\S{7})+)/

def result = input.collect {
  matcher = ( it =~ regexp )
  println "got $matcher.count for $it"
  matcher.collect { it[0] }
}

println result
```

I get the output

```
got 3 for AD ABCDEFG HIJKLMN
got 2 for AB HIJKLMN
got 4 for AC DJKEJKW SJKLAJL JSHELSJ
[[AD, ABCDEFG, HIJKLMN], [AB, HIJKLMN], [AC, DJKEJKW, SJKLAJL, JSHELSJ]]
```

Is this more what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

This pattern will match your requirements

```
^A[BCD](?:\s\S{7})+
```

See it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u1sg)

Meaning start with `A` then either a `B` or a `C` or a `D`. This is followed by at least one group consisting of a whitespace followed by 7 non whitespaces.

Comment: will not group it, but catch the complete line, so result is always 1.
but thanks for the cool link