# Enforce sequence and group same time with regex?

Tags: java, regex, groovy

A bit of continuation of [Get groups with regex and OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422817/get-groups-with-regex-and-or)

Sample

> AD ABCDEFG HIJKLMN
>       AB HIJKLMN
>       AC DJKEJKW SJKLAJL JSHELSJ

**Rule: Always 2 Chars Code (AB|AC|AD) at line beginning then any number (>1) of 7 Chars codes following (at least one 7char code). The space between the groups also can be a '.'**

With this expression I get it nicely grouped
`/^(AB|AC|AD)|((\S{7})+)/`
I can access the 2chars code with group[0] and so on.

Can I enforce the rule as above the same time ?

With above regex the following lines are also valid (because of the OR | in the regex statement)

> AC
>   dfghjkl
>   asdfgh hjklpoi

Which is not what I need.

Thanks again to the regex experts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would do this in two separate steps

1. I'd check the string matches a regular expression
2. I'd `split` matching strings based on the separator chars `[ .]`

This code:

```
def input = [
  'AD ABCDEFG HIJKLMN',
  'AB HIJKLMN',
  'AC DJKEJKW SJKLAJL JSHELSJ',
  'AC',
  'dfghjkl',
  'asdfgh hjklpoi',
  'AC DJKEJKW.SJKLAJL JSHELSJ',
]

def regexp = /^A[BCD]([ .](\S{7}))+$/

def result = input.inject( [] ) { list, inp ->
  // Does the line match the regexp?
  if( inp ==~ regexp ) {
    // If so, split it
    list << inp.split( /[ .]/ )
  }
  list
}

println result
```

Shows you an example of what I mean, and prints out:

```
[[AD, ABCDEFG, HIJKLMN], [AB, HIJKLMN], [AC, DJKEJKW, SJKLAJL, JSHELSJ], [AC, DJKEJKW, SJKLAJL, JSHELSJ]]
```

Comment: seems your approach is smarter/better performing than to execute 2 regex statements on the same line for the sake of 1. verification and 2.splitting Thanks !

Comment: And you'll be much happier when/if you ever need to edit it :-) good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
^(A[BCD])(([ .])([A-Z]{7}))+$
```